# Wifi - Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I am facing a major problem with the wifi connectivity in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The wifi was working properly initially but suddenly it stopped working. When I checked into the additional driver options it only contained my Nvidia GeForce drivers and had no wifi drivers. So I installed them but still its not showing them.

[image]

Comment: In case it had worked before your adapter may need a full reset, i.e. you have to fully remove power supply from the board (unplug from mains, remove battery).

Comment: Please post the exact response to these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: you can try "rfkill unblock all"